# VSCode: show default settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

## Problem

Previously, when editing the Preferences in VSCode, the available options where shown on the left, like this:
[image]

But suddenly, the available options are gone, and it's just like editing an ordinary JSON file:
[image]

## Question

How to get the available options back?

Answer (score 4):

Set `workbench.settings.useSplitJSON` to true.

This was changed in the [January 2019 release](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31). From the notes:

> If you really miss the split JSON editor with the default settings on the left, you can restore it by enabling the workbench.settings.useSplitJSON setting. Note that you will always be able to edit settings as JSON if that's what you prefer.

also,

> You can still see the listing of default settings with the Open Raw Default Settings command.

Comment: In vscode 1.51.1 the command to open the default settings files seems to actually be "Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)".

Comment: I didn't even know this was an option. Very cool and helpful thanks